# Characters' tone/pitch in dialogue

Tags: dialogue, description, tone

How does one go about showing a characters tone/pitch while talking?

For example, if someone said something that someone else doesn't believe and they reacted like:

> bullsHIIt

or

> whaAATt

Where the capitalized letters show a change in pitch from disbelief. Of course, the capitalized letters wouldn't be capitalized, so how would it be portrayed, or would it be left up for interpretation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine you are asking about fiction.

Spelling alterations similar to the ones proposed in the OP tend to have a comedic effect, and it seems to me that they are used to this effect in books for significantly younger audiences<sup>1</sup>.

In general depending on the tone of your story, you may have a *very limited* instances in which you alter the spelling<sup>2</sup>. The rest of the times you may be better off conveying the effect of a particular tone and pitch by showing the effect that such sound produces, or straight telling what the reader should hear.

For instance

> 'Whaaaat?' said Allison.

could be rendered as

> 'What?' said Allison in utter disbelief.

or

> 'What?' said Allison stretching the word to a long high-pitched squeak.

or

> 'What?' said Allison and everyone turned curious to grasp a glimpse of the person that spoke with such a foreign melody.

or

> 'What?' squealed Allison. Bob managed to empty his entire mug before she was finished.

or

> 'I already told you, it is of no consequence.' Said Bob, before Allison was done bellowing 'What?'.

or

> 'What?' said Allison. Bob chuckled, he still did not get used to her Southern accent.

<sub>[1]: this is from my own research across books for children as I wanted to write one.</sub>

<sub>[2]: not all spelling alterations are perceived similarly by all audiences. So while a Whaaat? may usually convey utter disbelief, a Hoooow? may at time convey similar disbelief, and other times boredom, or even grumpiness.</sub>

Comment: This is for a young adult fiction book, so, the spelling alteration won't actually be in the dialogue, but the effect it creates will, simply getting that across was confusing, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I agree NofP before me. Do not alter spelling of words to try and convey tone.

Show tone, by description.

> Alice responded in disdainful disbelief. "What?"
>
> Bob said, "Don't say it like that. I'm not crazy."

"Show don't tell" began with playwrights and moved to screenwriting; it literally meant do not have actors **say** things when they could **show** these things with acting or wardrobe or plots. Keep it visual. So nobody ever **tells** us Roger is a heavy smoker; we just **show** the audience that Roger always has a cigarette in his hand, and is always puffing on it.

When applied to novels, obviously everything is printed and "said" by the author, but the spirit of "Keep it visual" still applies. This does not mean altering the type face, or punctuation, or spelling or capitalization (although ALL CAPS might become common for shouted lines). And I have seen in professional scripts the "'sup" contraction for "what's up".

"Show don't tell" means describe the visual experience, to aid the reader's imagination of something happening.

Timing can appear in text, that is what punctuation is for. e.g.

> Catherine answered in cold anger. "Screw. You."
>
> Dave grinned. "Wait... Are you propositioning me?"
>
> Elaine was irritated. "Dave -- Just get out Dave. Now."

Do not try to convey tone with spelling changes. Convey tone with description, so the reader imagines the facial expressions, body language, emotions, etc. Weird spellings risk interrupting reader immersion as they are force to process weirdly spelled words. Description does not do that. And readers do not mind reading, shortening the text is not a justification for onomatopoeia.

Comment: however *do* convey slang and mispronunciation with spelling.

Comment: @Trish Sure, some slang cannot be represented any other way. I still don't think mixed case or non-letter symbols should be used, or any onomatopoeia spelling; if slang is some sound effect; as may accompany something like "blew my mind'. Then, *He gestured and made a sound to mimic an explosion.* Mispronunciation, I'm not so sure. instead of somebody saying "pet-tree dish", (it is pronounced pee-tree dish), I would write "petri dish", with an aside, *Jack mispronounces the word petri as pet-tree.* Otherwise, I think it does not look like "pet-tree", it looks like a typo.

Comment: ["It is possible that the two yutes..."](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104952/characters/nm0001304)

Comment: @Trish Fair. Except I would have spelled it "yoots"!

Comment: Was thinking of the "show, don't tell" thing but was simply confused on how I should go about it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are only **very** limited cases where alternate spellings are accepted, and all of them are about slang or mispronunciation, never for tone or pitch. They are better served by adding a few words about how those words are expressed or choosing the right word to replace say. For example, shriek or yell do convey by their own a whole lot of pitch and tone.

For an example when spelling alterations are ok, you could take the Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, where you get quite some words utterly *butchered* to get the mispronunciation and rolling of the tongue to the reader, but even there one does not find extended words. In the most part, you find replaced letters (or skipped ones) to give us how Jim pronounces words. They are decidedly not extended beyond their normal length.

> I made fast and laid down under Jim’s nose on the raft, and began to gap, and stretch my fists out against Jim, and says:
>
> “Hello, Jim, have I been asleep? Why didn’t you stir me up?”
>
> “Goodness gracious, is dat you, Huck? En you ain’ dead—you ain’ drownded—you’s back agin? It’s too good for true, honey, it’s too good for true. Lemme look at you chile, lemme feel o’ you. No, you ain’ dead! you’s back agin, ’live en soun’, jis de same ole Huck—de same ole Huck, thanks to goodness!”
>
> “What’s the matter with you, Jim? You been a-drinking?”
>
> “Drinkin’? Has I ben a-drinkin’? Has I had a chance to be a-drinkin’?”
>
> “Well, then, what makes you talk so wild?”
>
> “How does I talk wild?”
>
> “How? Why, hain’t you been talking about my coming back, and all that stuff, as if I’d been gone away?”
>
> “Huck—Huck Finn, you look me in de eye; look me in de eye. Hain’t you ben gone away?”

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, the convention is that you don't directly indicate tone, pitch or stress in prose. Like the other replies show, there are ways you can generally hint at it, but you don't show specifically where the rise in pitch might be, for example.

Instead, you should try to write dialogue in such a way that it doesn't rely on a specific intonation to carry meaning. If that means your characters are more wordy than they would be in real life, that's fine.